# Общий стиль для всех сборок (XAML, WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть главное приложение WPF.И есть несколько других библиотек пользовательских элементов. Для того, чтобы все компоненты выглядели одинаково хочу использовать отдельную сборку, где будут храниться все стили. Не могу никак все это соединить. Как это делается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляем ResourceDictonary, называем его Generic.xaml туда пишем все подключаемые стили, подключаем сборку к проекту, ссылаемся на этот Generic.xaml из App.xaml.
Пример:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Button.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="TabPanel.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/LibraryDictonaries;component/TabPanel.xaml" />
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Обязательно называть "Generic.xaml"?

Comment: Нет, но так обычно делают :)

Comment: Иначе считается дурным тоном?)

Comment: Ну а как его еще назвать? Универсальный, тут по моему очень хорошо подходит :)